# Shortening URLS

Tags: url, redirect, url-rewriting, url-shortener

Basically i want to do this,

**www.mydomain.com/index.html** >> change to >> **www.mydomain.com/**

and checkout for example,

**www.mydomain.com/cart.php** >> change to >> **www.mydomain.com/cart/**

**www.mydomain.com/checkout.php** >> change to >> **www.mydomain.com/checkout/**

Would i do this in .htaccess? i have no idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please, you can modify your title to modifiy php urls, or something like that, because this question can be easily confused with algorithms for url shortener like bit.ly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule   ^cart/([0-9]+)   cart.php?ID=$1 [L]
```

This will allow `www.mydomain.com/cart/` to run `cart.php` with any numerical id after the slash to the appended as an id.

Answer (score 2):

Use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to do this.

There are some examples on this page. :)